# Iphone Differentiate between lite version and full version

Tags: iphone

I have developed an app for iphone. it is quiz app.
It has main topics say 5.
All topics has 20 question.
Now I want to create lite and full version.
in Lite Version, when user download app, user gets 5 question in all topics.
and in full version user can buy topic wise.
for eg there are topic 1,2,..5. user want to buy topic 2 and topic 3,
then how can i develop code for this functionality.
I know this is possible, but how that I dont know.

Please help in this case and suggest best solution.

thankyou all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of developing two separate versions of the application, ship a fully function application with limited choices available for little or no charge.

Use in-app purchasing to give the user the option of selecting more topics that they could buy for a nominal charge.  This will help you keep your code organized without limiting how little or how much the user will potentially buy once they have your application.

here is the documentation for such a feat: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

To expand: The Apple docs on in-app purchasing contain code given in stepwise fashion with associated explanations.  Try out their code if this is the direction that you want to take and then maybe some new questions will form in your mind that you can bring back to stackoverflow!

Comment: Thankyou for your reply, but my question is how to code this differetiate. i have lite version i m ready to upload to itunes, but it would be free version, and how to code full version topic vise. suggest code if possible. thanks again

Comment: has explained the basic concept and has given you a link to the relevant documentation which includes code samples. That answers your question and it would be good manners to accept the answer. If you want a ready-made product, you should hire @samfu_1 or another developer to carry out the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Create one mega app.  Make that app free.  Then put an in app store inside the app.  The store will offer the ability to purchase the new topics.  Use in-app-purchase to do this.  Apple provides great docs for this or the internet can also help.

Then in the app, but default only have how ever many topics available.  Have the in-app-purchase link to `NSUSerDefaults` so when the user purchases a new topic, the app will now "know" to allow the user to use that topic.  Then when they are looking at the list of topics, just check your `NSUserDefaults` to see which topics are available.

That should do it.

Comment: hi..means user will click on some button from where he/she can doenload full app. but how it will be managed..?

Comment: you cannot put a button that forces the user to download the app from inside your app.  Currently, theres no way to do that.  You can provide a link to the app store and then the user may or may not purchase your app.  I would do the method I described above.  You manage the entire thing from within one app.  Easy to manage and simple.